# Excel - auto number only non blank rows

Tags: excel, count, row

I need to auto number rows that are non blank dynamically. The rows are in a report and will be blank or nonblank from time to time in any of b:j columns as the work report changes.
I need the sequential number of the **nonblank** row in column a.

Answer (score 0):

If starting from row 2:

```
=IF(COUNTA(B2:j2),MAX(A$1:A1)+1,"")
```

[image]